# VideoCapture read() returns True when USB Camera is disconnected

Tags: python, opencv, camera

When I disconnect the USB camera the read() function returns True, so program doesnt try reconnect itself, it outputs a black image.

When I start the program with the USB camara disconnected it reports the same.

self.stream.isOpened() returns True too.

```
class VideoGet:
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        self.src = src
        self.stopped = False
        self.Q = []
        self.scale_percent = 100
        self.grabbed = False
        self.frame = None
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(self.src)
    def start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.get, args=()).start()
        return self
    def get(self):

        while True:
            self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(self.src)
            (self.grabbed, preFrame) = self.stream.read()
            if self.grabbed is True:
                print('Iniciando camara')
                while True:
                    try:
                        (self.grabbed, preFrame) = self.stream.read()
                        self.width = int(preFrame.shape[1] * self.scale_percent / 100)
                        self.height = int(preFrame.shape[0] * self.scale_percent / 100)
                        dim = (self.width, self.height)
                        self.frame = cv2.resize(preFrame, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
                        if len(self.Q) >= cfg['config']['tiempoPre']:
                            self.Q.pop(0)
                            self.Q.append(self.frame)
                        else:
                            self.Q.append(self.frame)
                    except Exception as e:
                        self.grabbed = False
                        self.stream.release()
                        del(self.stream)
                        break

    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True
```

Edit: When reconnecting to IP Camera it works perfect.

Edit2: Solved the problem by reading the image and doing an np.sum, then checking if the value is bigger than a threshold.

Comment: what exactly happens when you disconnect? What kind of images does your program get? You can always check whether the image is empty or not. Maybe in your case, getting result true + image is empty means that the camera was disconnected? If the image is not empty, maybe the driver still has images in a buffer? This could mean that your program is capturing too slow.

Comment: When I disconnect I get images, but they are black, so as you say I'm checking whether the image is "empty", (is not completely black) setting a value where the np.sum is lower than a value.

Comment: probably a misconcept in the driver implementation...